# Put Option Settlement for All-Cash Acquisition with a CVR?

Tags: corporate-acquisition, put-options

How are in-the-money put options settled when an acquisition price includes a contingent value right (CVR) that causes the stock to trade above the acquisition price?

Example:  Alder Bio acquired for $18.00 cash + a CVR of $2.00 when drug approved in Europe. Trading at $18.75.

How would a $20.00 in-the-money put cash settle, at $2.00 or at $1.25?

The $20.00 put option is trading ~$2.00 which would allow shareholders to fully protect their shares and receive the CVR at no incremental cost if the option would cash settle at put strike ($20) - acquisition price ($18.00) = $2.00.

Comment: Shareholders receive the CVR not option owners. Options settle based on expiration price. If there takeover, based on takeover price. If OTM, the option worth nothing. If ITM, worth intrinsic value (final price-strike). I'm not familiar with CVRs. I can say when these additional securities are thrown into the mix, it becomes very hard to figure out the bottom line, even if you find the settlement terms at an option exchange's web site or the OCC (in U.S.). In such cases, it's a good idea to contact option exchange. In US, that's the CBOE. Elsewhere, I don't know. Start Googling :->)